# Org-mode cache does not work when using var

Tags: emacs, org-mode

The Org-mode cache option, see https://orgmode.org/manual/cache.html, saves a lot of time when exporting to html. Unfortunately I cannot get it working when passing var parameters.

This is how it looks like in Org:

```
  #+tblname: howtocache
  | x | y |
  |---+---|
  | 1 | 5 |
  | 2 | 2 |
  | 3 | 1 |
  | 4 | 6 |
  | 5 | 3 |

  #+begin_src gnuplot :cache yes :var data=howtocache :exports code :file howtocache.png
  reset

  plot data u 1:2 w l
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS[4a0d86e3196a769ad675be613318b8fb77d47f2e]:
  [[file:howtocache.png]]
```

When I evaluate the gnuplot block I always get a new hash value.

In the *gnuplot* buffer I see the data is provided from a different temporary file.

- One run:
  data = "c:/Users/harald/AppData/Local/Temp/babel-14152bAf/gnuplot-141521-y"
- Another run:
  data = "c:/Users/harald/AppData/Local/Temp/babel-14152bAf/gnuplot-14152OnU"

Probably the hash is calculated based on the filename.

The main question is: How can I use cache together with var?

Comment: This is an interesting question. IMHO I fear it is not possible to take into account cached variables, but only to cache some code block results.

Comment: You should ask the question on the [orgmode mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode).

Answer (score 1):

Found a reasonable solution on:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/24126

> Evaluate manually on change, not on export
>
> Put `:eval no-export` in your header arguments, and the processing won't
>   happen on export, only when you manually call it with `C-c C-c` or 
>   `M-x org-babel-execute-buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your infomration about the changing temp file, I've found a general solution for gnuplot caching that works for both regular execution and exporting.  Rather than passing data directly to the gnuplot src block and letting ob-gnuplot write a temp file, I write the temp file myself, cached it, and passed the file name to the gnuplot src block instead.  This works because ob-gnuplot only writes files for vectors in its input, and we're bypassing that by giving it a string instead.

Here's some code to illustrate, based on the example above:

```
  #+tblname: howtocache
  | x | y |
  |---+---|
  | 1 | 5 |
  | 2 | 2 |
  | 3 | 1 |
  | 4 | 6 |
  | 5 | 3 |

  #+name: data-file
  #+begin_src elisp :cache yes :var data=howtocache
  (org-babel-gnuplot-table-to-data data (org-babel-temp-file "gnuplot-") '())
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS[25d02647c9b4a748ce6798d81e70d72c3ace0846]: data-file
  : /var/folders/n4/vg52wwmn02xbfx_4g2l53z1m0000gn/T/babel-eiHU75/gnuplot-8osPqw

  #+begin_src gnuplot :cache yes :var data=data-file :exports code :file howtocache.png
  reset

  plot data u 1:2 w l
  #+end_src

  #+RESULTS[af6331cf9eac29a503e86eb07dc76a1a0d808f85]:
  [[file:howtocache.png]]
```

Hopefully this will be useful to future googlers of this thread, with the same use-case